# Divergence of the Riemann integral of a particular function in $(0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus

Let $f_1(x)=\frac{1}{x(1+|\ln(x)|)^2}\ \forall x\in (0,\infty)$ and the point is to prove that if $q\in (0,\infty)$:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^q(1+|\ln(x)|)^{2q}}dx<\infty \Leftrightarrow q=1$$

So the point is to bound from below $\ f_1^q\ $ with a function whose integral goes to $\infty, \forall q\ne1$ (since I've already proved that $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^q(1+|\ln(x)|)^{2q}}dx<\infty$, for $q=1$).

I started by analyzing two cases: for $x\in (0,1)$ and $x\in (1,\infty)$.

For $x\in (0,1)$ and $q\in (1,\infty)$:
$$\ln(x)<0 \Rightarrow |\ln(x)|=-\ln(x)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

$$\Rightarrow\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^q(1+|\ln(x)|)^{2q}}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^q\left(1+\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{2q}}dx;\ $$

from here there's a hint: $\rho\left(1+\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\le\frac{1}{x^{\rho}}$ for $\rho\in(0,1)$ but a I can't find a way to connect this with  the integral above to bound it from below. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use that for $\varepsilon>0$, you have $x^{\varepsilon}(1+|\log(x)|^{2q})\to 0$ as $x\to 0$. This imply that $x^{\varepsilon}(1+|\log(x)|^{2q})$ is bounded, say by $M$, on $]0,1]$. Now if you choose $\varepsilon$ such that $q-\varepsilon>1$, you can use that if $f$ is your function, you have $\displaystyle f(x)\geq \frac{M^{-1}}{x^{q-\varepsilon}}$.

Comment: Ok I got it. So choosing $\epsilon = q-1 > 0\ (q>1)$ we have that:
$$x^{q-1}(1+|log(x)|)^{2q}\le M \Leftrightarrow x^{q}(1+|log(x)|)^{2q}\le xM \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{x^{q}(1+|log(x)|)^{2q}} \ge \frac{1}{xM}$$

Comment: And, thus:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{xM}dx \le \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{q}(1+|log(x)|)^{2q}}$$
where
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{xM}dx=\frac{1}{M} (0-\lim_{x\to 0} log(x))=\frac{1}{M} (\infty) = \infty$$

Thanks!